# Spring WebFlux webclient handle ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am using the Spring WebFlux webclient to make REST calls. I've configured the connection timeout on `3000` milliseconds, accordingly:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> options
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 3000)))
    .build();

return webClient.get()
    .uri("http://localhost:8081/resource")
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
        // Some logging..
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    .bodyToMono(MyPojo.class);
```

The `onStatus` method is returning an empty `Mono` for every `400` / `500` response code. How can I do the same for a connection timeout and maybe even read / write timeouts. As right now its just throwing a `io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException` which is not handled by the `onStatus`

I don't need an `@ExceptionHandler` on my controller, as these REST calls are part of a more complex flow, and via an empty `Mono` the element should just be ignored.

Back in `spring-web` with a `RestTemplate`, I remember the connection timeout also resulted in a `RestClientException`. So we could just catch the `RestClientException` for all exceptions and timeouts. Is there a way we can do this with `WebClient` as well?

Comment: I tried your code, but I get a `NullPointerException` if I return `Mono.empty()`. Did that really work for you? The documentation says that you have to throw an exception instead of returning `Mono.empty()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reactor offers multiple `onError***` operators for this:

```
return webClient.get()
    .uri("http://localhost:8081/resource")
    .retrieve()
    .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.empty())
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
        // Some logging..
        return Mono.empty();
    })
    .bodyToMono(MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: Why don't return Mono.error() instead of Mono.empty() ?

Comment: That is what the OP asked about at the time.